# Plesk - TYPO3 10LTS - Client denied by server configuration error when trying to access page module & fail2ban locked

Tags: typo3, plesk, fail2ban, typo3-10.x

I installed a new typo3 10lts via composer linux plesk obsidian 18.0.27 and ubuntu 16lts.

When trying to acces the page module, I get such errors in the error_log:

```
evasive20:error pid 5442 client denied by server configuration: /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/test-composer/public/typo3/index.php, referer: https://domain/typo3/index.php?route=%2Fmain&token=df1d870594fbb7e7a90csdf69esdf0af6f97sdf9b
evasive20:error pid 5442 client denied by server configuration: /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/test-composer/public/typo3/sysext/core/Resources/Public/Icons/T3Icons/actions/actions-filter.svg, referer: https://domain/typo3/index.php?route=%2Fmain&token=df1d870594fbb7e7a90csdf69esdf0af6f97sdf9b
evasive20:error pid 5442 client denied by server configuration: /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/test-composer/public/typo3/sysext/core/Resources/Public/Icons/T3Icons/actions/actions-refresh.svg, referer: https://domain/typo3/index.php?route=%2Fmain&token=df1d870594fbb7e7a90csdf69esdf0af6f97sdf9b
evasive20:error pid 1868 client denied by server configuration: /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/test-composer/public/typo3/index.php, referer: https://domain/typo3/index.php?route=%2Fmain&token=df1d870594fbb7e7a90csdf69esdf0af6f97sdf9b
```

... the browser freezes and the my IP gets thrown in fail2boan.

On the same server I have another test domain with the same php settings and installed TYPO3 via plesk, there everything is working ... yet they have an old 8.7LTS.

Also when trying to install the introduction package, I get tis error:

```
evasive20:error pid 26284 client IP:45854 client denied by server configuration: /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/test-composer/typo3/install.php, referer: https://domain/typo3/install.php?install[controller]=environment&install[context]=backend
```

How can I solve this and what do I need to do (step-by-step)?

php 7.3
apache 4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue some time ago.

For me, It turned out that a symlink was assigned to a falsy user. Make sure that the symlink you're is assigned to the proper user:group. In most cases this is the user which the PHP handler is executed:

`chown -h <subscription_user>:psacln /var/www/vhosts/example.com/symlink`

One additional thing you should check is that Apache is able to access symlinks. Make sure that the following directive is present in your `.htaccess` file:

`Options +FollowSymlinks`

Comment: Unfortunately didn't help and I get thrown in fail2ban jail (plesk-apache) when trying to access the page module